# How to declare an array in another array without define the size

Tags: c

I want to define an array without size and it contains an array without siez as well.

Here after the function :

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct dm_key_reg {
    char *obj;
    char **ukey;
}DMKEYREG;

DMKEYREG tab_reg_key[]={
{"Device_SS", {"SerialSS", "SSS"}},
{"Device__AP", {"SerialAP", "III"}},
{"Device___EP", { "SerialEP", "EEE", "CCC"}},
{0}
};

int main(void)
{
DMKEYREG *tab_key = tab_reg_key;
for (; tab_key->obj; tab_key++) {
    printf("obj= %s\n",tab_key->obj);
}
}
```

But when build this example I got the following warning :

```
test.c:9:1: warning: braces around scalar initializer
 {"Device_SS", {"SerialSS", "SSS"}},
 ^
test.c:9:1: note: (near initialization for ‘tab_reg_key[0].ukey’)
test.c:9:16: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 {"Device_SS", {"SerialSS", "SSS"}},
                ^
test.c:9:16: note: (near initialization for ‘tab_reg_key[0].ukey’)
test.c:9:28: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
 {"Device_SS", {"SerialSS", "SSS"}},
                            ^
test.c:9:28: note: (near initialization for ‘tab_reg_key[0].ukey’)
test.c:10:1: warning: braces around scalar initializer
 {"Device__AP", {"SerialAP", "III"}},
 ^
test.c:10:1: note: (near initialization for ‘tab_reg_key[1].ukey’)
test.c:10:17: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 {"Device__AP", {"SerialAP", "III"}},
                 ^
test.c:10:17: note: (near initialization for ‘tab_reg_key[1].ukey’)
test.c:10:29: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
 {"Device__AP", {"SerialAP", "III"}},
                             ^
test.c:10:29: note: (near initialization for ‘tab_reg_key[1].ukey’)
test.c:11:1: warning: braces around scalar initializer
 {"Device___EP", { "SerialEP", "EEE", "CCC"}},
 ^
test.c:11:1: note: (near initialization for ‘tab_reg_key[2].ukey’)
test.c:11:19: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 {"Device___EP", { "SerialEP", "EEE", "CCC"}},
                   ^
test.c:11:19: note: (near initialization for ‘tab_reg_key[2].ukey’)
test.c:11:31: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
 {"Device___EP", { "SerialEP", "EEE", "CCC"}},
                               ^
test.c:11:31: note: (near initialization for ‘tab_reg_key[2].ukey’)
test.c:11:38: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
 {"Device___EP", { "SerialEP", "EEE", "CCC"}},
                                      ^
test.c:11:38: note: (near initialization for ‘tab_reg_key[2].ukey’)
zribi@zribi-ThinkPad-E480:~/Bureau$ ./test 
obj= Device_SS
obj= Device__AP
obj= Device___EP
```

is it possible to avoid these warnings !

Comment: This is wrong in many ways. The correct way to do it depends on if you need the data to be read-only or read-write.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting warnings because you're trying to initialize a `char **` as if it were an array.  That creates another warning because you're trying to initialize a `char **` with a `char *`.

You can get around this by creating compound literals whose types are an array of `char *`, i.e. `char *[]`, which will decay to the desired type of `char **`.  You should also change the type to `const char **` since you have string literals which can't be changed.

```
typedef struct dm_key_reg {
    const char *obj;
    const char **ukey;
}DMKEYREG;

DMKEYREG tab_reg_key[]={
    {"Device_SS", (const char *[]){"SerialSS", "SSS", NULL}},
    {"Device__AP", (const char *[]){"SerialAP", "III", NULL}},
    {"Device___EP", (const char *[]){ "SerialEP", "EEE", "CCC", NULL}},
    {0}
};
```

Note also that you'll need to add a NULL delimiter to the end of each list so you know when you've reached the end.

Comment: @Lundin Agreed.  Updated.

Answer (score 0):

`char **ukey` is not an array, nor is it a pointer to an array. It can however be a pointer to the first element in a an array of pointers. That means that each initializer assigned to `ukey` needs to be an array of pointers (to char). You can do this by declaring such arrays of pointers as *compound literals*, in this case

`(const char*[]){ /* data here */ }`.

Second, all *string literals* (`"this stuff"`) are read-only. So you should *always* `const` qualify pointers to string literals or otherwise someone might accidentally write access them, which invokes undefined behavior. (If you need the data to have read/write access, then it's a whole different story.)

In this case, it means that both objects of the struct must be const qualified. And then you might as well make the struct object const too.

A corrected, safe version might look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct dm_key_reg 
{
  const char*  obj;
  const char** ukey;
}DMKEYREG;

const DMKEYREG tab_reg_key[] =
{
  { .obj  = "Device_SS",
    .ukey = (const char*[]){"SerialSS", "SSS"} },
  { .obj  = "Device__AP", 
    .ukey = (const char*[]){"SerialAP", "III"} },
  { .obj  = "Device___EP",
    .ukey = (const char*[]){"SerialEP", "EEE", "CCC"}},
  {0}
};

int main(void)
{
  const DMKEYREG* tab_key = tab_reg_key;
  for (; tab_key->obj!=NULL; tab_key++) 
  {
    printf("obj= %s\n",tab_key->obj);
  }
}
```

Also consider using a NULL sentinel value at the end of each string list. That is:

`(const char*[]){"SerialSS", "SSS", NULL}`

Otherwise you have no way of knowing how many strings that are stored in that array, since you don't save the array size.

Answer (score -1):

here after the solution :

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define LIST_KEY (const char *[])
typedef struct dm_key_reg {
    char *obj;
    const char **ukey;
}DMKEYREG;

DMKEYREG tab_reg_key[]={
{"Device_SS", LIST_KEY{"SerialSS", "SSS"}},
{"Device__AP", LIST_KEY{"SerialAP", "III"}},
{"Device___EP", LIST_KEY{ "SerialEP", "EEE", "CCC"}},
{0}
};

int main(void)
{
DMKEYREG *tab_key = tab_reg_key;
for (; tab_key->obj; tab_key++) {
    printf("obj= %s\n",tab_key->obj);
    printf("ukey0= %s\n",tab_key->ukey[0]);
    printf("ukey1= %s\n",tab_key->ukey[1]);
}
}
```

Comment: The macro is nothing but obfuscation though, you should drop that one.